# I cant add class to nth-child

Tags: javascript

**HTML:**

```
        <div id="brojac-poteza" style="clear:both;padding-top:40px;padding-left:60px;padding-right:40px">
            <div class="round-end darker-back card-choice">1</div>
            <div class="darker-back card-choice">2</div>
            <div class="darker-back card-choice">3</div>
            <div class="darker-back card-choice">4</div>
            <div class="darker-back card-choice">6</div>
            <div class="darker-back card-choice">5</div>
            <div class="darker-back card-choice">7</div>
            <div class="darker-back card-choice">8</div>
            <div class="darker-back card-choice">9</div>
            <div class="darker-back card-choice">10</div>
        </div>
```

**`script.js`** (above this code I set `var g = 1;`)

```
g += 1;

$('#brojac-poteza:nth-child(g)').addClass('round-end');
```

When I test it says `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-child`

Comment: Try this: `$('#brojac-poteza:nth-child('+ g +')').addClass('round-end');`

Answer (score 1):

change it to

```
$('#brojac-poteza:eq('+g+')').addClass('round-end');
```

Comment: Now I dont get this error, but class still didnt added o.O

Answer (score 1):

First you need to use variable g not g as string and find nth of children not on root:

```js
var g = 5;
$('#brojac-poteza div:nth-child(' + g + ')').addClass('round-end');
```

```css
.round-end {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="brojac-poteza" style="clear:both;padding-top:40px;padding-left:60px;padding-right:40px">
  <div class="round-end darker-back card-choice">1</div>
  <div class="darker-back card-choice">2</div>
  <div class="darker-back card-choice">3</div>
  <div class="darker-back card-choice">4</div>
  <div class="darker-back card-choice">6</div>
  <div class="darker-back card-choice">5</div>
  <div class="darker-back card-choice">7</div>
  <div class="darker-back card-choice">8</div>
  <div class="darker-back card-choice">9</div>
  <div class="darker-back card-choice">10</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try these solution also :-

```
$('#brojac-poteza .darker-back:nth-child(' + g + ')').addClass('round-end');
```

It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to count the `.darker-black` elements by doing this for example:

```
$(function() {
    var numItems = $('#brojac-poteza .darker-back').length; /* Count items */
    var odd = 2; /* Change the steps here if you like to */

    /* Now loop it, and skip 1 step, 1, 3, 5 ... */
    for(g = 1; g < numItems; g+=odd) {
        $('#brojac-poteza div:nth-child(' + g + ')').addClass('test');
        console.log(g);
    }
});
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r2ncLpLb/1/

I hope this will work for you either :)